# no such table: tasks

Tags: sqlite, go, crud, go-gin

Today i am starting to learn simple CRUD in go using gin-gonic, gorm, go-playground, and sqlite, but i am having problems running the POST Method in Postman. when I run the POST method. In my console window it shows: no such table: tasks. Even though I created the table using db.AutoMigrate(&Task{}), can anyone help me:
Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10"
    "gorm.io/driver/sqlite"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "net/http"
)

// Task model
type Task struct {
    gorm.Model
    Title     string `json:"title" validate:"required"`
    Completed bool   `json:"completed"`
}

var db *gorm.DB
var validate *validator.Validate

func init() {
    var err error
    db, err = gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("test.db"), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic("Failed to connect to database")
    }

    db.AutoMigrate(&Task{})
    validate = validator.New()
}

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()

    r.GET("/tasks", getTasks)
    
    r.POST("/tasks", createTask)

    r.PUT("/tasks/:id", updateTask)

    r.DELETE("/tasks/:id", deleteTask)

    r.Run(":8080")
}

// Handler để lấy danh sách công việc
func getTasks(c *gin.Context) {
    var tasks []Task
    db.Find(&tasks)
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, tasks)
}

func createTask(c *gin.Context) {
    var task Task
    if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&task); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
        return
    }

    if err := validate.Struct(task); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
        return
    }

    db.Create(&task)
    c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, task)
}

func updateTask(c *gin.Context) {
    id := c.Param("id")
    var task Task
    if err := db.First(&task, id).Error; err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusNotFound, gin.H{"error": "Task not found"})
        return
    }

    if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&task); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
        return
    }

    if err := validate.Struct(task); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
        return
    }

    db.Save(&task)
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, task)
}

func deleteTask(c *gin.Context) {
    id := c.Param("id")
    var task Task
    if err := db.First(&task, id).Error; err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusNotFound, gin.H{"error": "Task not found"})
        return
    }

    db.Delete(&task)
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"message": fmt.Sprintf("Task %s deleted", id)})
}
```

This is what I get in the console when I press send in the POST method:

```
2023/11/20 19:46:10 D:/DOWNLOAD/Golang_Projects/todo_list/main.go:85 no such table: tasks
[0.634ms] [rows:0] INSERT INTO `tasks` (`title`,`completed`,`created_at`,`updated_at`) VALUES ("Buy groceries",false,"2023-11-20 19:46:10.471","2023-11-20 19:46:10.471") RETURNING `id`
[GIN] 2023/11/20 - 19:46:10 | 500 |       634.5µs |             ::1 | POST     "/tasks"
```

Comment: you should handle the error from `db.Save()` and other database functions in order to solve such errors. In golang always handle errors generally.